# how can i access this json in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

this is my json

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Error": {
            "ErrorCode": 0,
            "ErrorMessage": ""
        },
        "Results": {
            "FareBreakdown": [{
                    "Currency": "INR"
                }
            ],
            "FareRules": [{
                "Origin": "DEL"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

this my script

```
   const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/fare-quote",
          requestData
        );

        this.searchResul = response.data.Response.FareBreakdown;

        console.log(this.searchResul)
```

i get undefined in my console

this how i use in my template to show the data

```
 {{searchResul}}
```

i get a good response but i'm just trying to display the data in my template

Comment: Everything is before your eyes. There's no Response.FareBreakdown because it's Response.Results.FareBreakdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do these

```
  this.searchResul = response.data.Response.Results.FareBreakdown;
```

then in your template

```
 <li v-for="item in searchResul" :key="item.Currency">
      Currency: {{ item.Currency }}
      </li>
```